# $state.go() doesn't load controller in ionic application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Using the following code, when a page with `id=0` loads first time there is no problem with controller. But when again the same page loads with same `id=0` again, it does not loads controller.

```
$state.go('tab.dash', {
  id: $rootScope.products[CONSTANTS.i].id
}, {
  reload: true
});
```

How does it happen? Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: u need to show more code to get an overall idea of what the problem is.

Comment: For better perfomance ionic cached a lot for things, try adding this cache-view="false"

Comment: The reload property is a property for the angular ui router and not ionic. Ionic is caching your view and controller by default. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792166/routing-issue-with-ui-router-in-ionic-angularjs/29806611#29806611 to fix your porblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem where I needed stats to recalculate every time a tab was visited.

You need to disable view caching. You can do so in the route setup. For example:

```
.state('tab.stats', {
 url: '/stats',
 views: {
   'tab-stats': {
     templateUrl: 'templates/tab-stats.html',
     controller: 'StatsCtrl'
   }
 },
 cache: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

well, When you cache the view (by default it is true) controller is loaded only at first time and on subsequent navigation it will attach and detach the scope. Cacheing helping with the performance of single page applications. If you dont want to disable the caching then you use the ionic view events like (enter, leave,loaded and so on).

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
            // ur stuff in here....
        });
```