# Routing issue with ui-router in ionic (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have UI routes defined in ionic, and made a `console.log` in controller, but my problem is when I switch between URLs using ng-href="/#/LINK" then no data displayed in console, but when I refresh the same page I am able to see the data in console .... let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Routes -

```
  .state('app.roomone', {
    url: "/roomone/:id",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/roomone.html",
        controller: 'RoomoneCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.roomtwo', {
    url: "/selecroom/:roomname/:roomindex",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/roomtwo.html",
        controller: 'RoomtwoCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Following are my controllers -

```
.controller('RoomoneCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  console.log("I am in room one");
});

.controller('RoomtwoCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  console.log("I am in room two");
});
```

In my template - I am having simple -- `<a ng-href="/#/roomone/MY_ID" />Dummy Link</a>`

Problem - Only on refresh(F5) I am getting console values like ""I am in room one"" not on simple navigation of link. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: that is because of caching issue, you need to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827928/template-does-not-update-when-using-ui-router-and-ion-tabs

Comment: @pankajparkar on using `cache: false` it is throwing error - `Error: ctrlB is nullleave@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43279:23`

Comment: try doing 1 & 2 option in that answer

Comment: @pankajparkar getting same error int he console..though functionality wise its working ..I am using version - v1.0.0-beta.14 ...how do i downgrade to 13 as per your post ?

Comment: get that javascript from here https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.0.0-beta.13/js/ionic.bundle.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments: the view is cashed and therefore the controller is not initialized the second time you visit the page.

One solution was not mentioned in [Template does not update when using ui-router and ion-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827928/template-does-not-update-when-using-ui-router-and-ion-tabs). (change cashing to false in view or in router) therefor I adding an extra answer here (better was adding it to comments but with the code example this would become unclear)

Listen in your controller (or directive) to the $ionicView.beforeEnter event to know when a view is active.

```
.controller('RoomoneCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
        // (on first time added to DOM and after the view becomes active after cached
        // change some value on your scope
        $scope.date = new Date();
        console.log("I am in room one");
    });
});
```

For ionic view events see: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced the same issue. This is a cache issue. I have fixed the issue by using **cache : false**.You have have add it in your route as the below,

```
.state('app.roomone', {
    url: "/roomone/:id",
    cache : false,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/roomone.html",
        controller: 'RoomoneCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.roomtwo', {
    url: "/selecroom/:roomname/:roomindex",
    cache : false,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/roomtwo.html",
        controller: 'RoomtwoCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```